# Pdf Merge with itext sharp

Tags: c#, pdf, merge, itext

I am trying to create a desktop application combining existing pdf files into one.

I found some code that helps me with my design and selecting the files and merging them but my code creates pdf files and then sends the new file to the desktop. I need my code to grab existing pdf files and merging them together to create a file with those files together and have it sent to my desktop. Attached is my code, please let me know what I need to fix. I am very new to C# I understand basics but I am unsure where to change things and how to in this certain area.

```
namespace mergePdf
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnMerge_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Folder that we'll work from
            string workingFolder = 
            Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
            string pdf1 = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "pdf1.pdf");//PDF 
            with solid red background color
            string pdf2 = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "pdf2.pdf");//PDF 
            with text
            string pdf3 = Path.Combine(workingFolder, "pdf3.pdf"); 
            //Merged PDF

            //Create a basic PDF filled with red, nothing special
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf1, FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
                    fs))
                    {
                        doc.Open();
                        PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
                        cb.SetColorFill(BaseColor.RED);
                        cb.Rectangle(0, 0, doc.PageSize.Width, 
                        doc.PageSize.Height);
                        cb.Fill();
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Create a basic PDF with a single line of text, nothing 
            special
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf2, FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
                    fs))
                    {
                        doc.Open();
                        doc.Add(new Paragraph("This is a test"));
                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }
            }

            //Create a basic PDF
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(pdf3, FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                using (Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER))
                {
                    using (PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, 
                    fs))
                    {
                        doc.Open();

                        //Get page 1 of the first file
                        PdfImportedPage imp1 = writer.GetImportedPage(new 
                        PdfReader(pdf1), 1);
                        //Get page 2 of the second file
                        PdfImportedPage imp2 = writer.GetImportedPage(new 
                        PdfReader(pdf2), 1);
                        //Add the first file to coordinates 0,0
                        writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp1, 0, 0);
                        //Since we don't call NewPage the next call will 
                        operate on the same page
                        writer.DirectContent.AddTemplate(imp2, 0, 0);
                        doc.Close();

                    }
                }
            }

            this.Close();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBoxPdfFile1Path.Text = 
            System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, 
            @"C:\Users\jesse\Downloads");
            textBoxPdfFile2Path.Text = 
            System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, 
            @"C:\Users\jesse\Downloads");

        }

        private void btnSelectFile1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
            fd.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxPdfFile1Path.Text = fd.FileName;
            }
        }

        private void btnSelectFile2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog fd = new OpenFileDialog();
            fd.Filter = "PDF files (*.pdf)|*.pdf|All files (*.*)|*.*";
            if (fd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                textBoxPdfFile2Path.Text = fd.FileName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I expect the output to combine existing files into one file which will be sent to my desktop. Right now it creates two pdf sample files and combines them but I have no idea how to select from existing instead.

Answer (score 0):

Using the below code should do what you want as far merging the documents.
 To get a list of the actual paths to the individual pdfs is up to you on how to do.
 Once the FileStream is closed your document should be created at the specified 'newPdfPath' path.

```
using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(newPdfPath, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    Document document = new Document();
                    PdfCopy pdf = new PdfCopy(document, stream);
                    PdfReader reader = null;
                    document.Open();
                    foreach (var item in listOfPathsToPDFs)
                    {                       
                        reader = new PdfReader(item);
                        pdf.AddDocument(reader);
                        reader.Close();                        
                    }
                    document.Close();
                }
```